# Matching element that does not have specific element

Tags: jquery

I need to run through html blocks with .myEm class and remove a class from a first div in that element if .myEm doe not have any `<p>` tags.

This is what I came up with, but it still does not remove the class. What am I missing?

```
$('.myEm').each(function() {
    $(this).not(':has(p)').find('.row:first-child').removeClass('myClass');
});
```

Comment: Can you please post sample relevant markup or a demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do that in once sweep; many of the jQuery methods use `.each()` internally:

```
$('.myEm:not(:has(p)) .row:first-child').removeClass('myClass');
```

Comment: I actually have .each() loop to accommodate other functionality.

Comment: I see. However, if that functionality does not operate on non-matched elements, you can chain `each()` after `removeClass()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()` and check the `length`

```
$('.myEm').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('p').length == 0){
        $(this).find('.row:first-child').removeClass('myClass');
    }
});
```